# How To Restrict Multiple clicks For Button in Different Browswers?

Tags: angularjs

I have a button which on click will save the form information. The problem is, user instead of clicking 1's on the "Save" button clicks on it multiple times as long as it disappears on the screen. With this, I am saving same form which inturn throw duplicate exceptions.

Comment: usually you would check if the data already exists before saving, you can't prevent much in the front-end as the user is in full charge of it

Comment: Obfuscate the page with a spinner when an API request is pending, in other words, after the first submit button click. e.g. using http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property by name `$scope.isLoading = false` and when pressing *you can disable the input by this property like that `$scope.isLoading = true`

and assign the button to this property like that:

```
<input type="button" ng-disabled="isLoading" />
```

after you return from server, you can assign it back to false :

```
$scope.isLoading = false
```